# A question about the coefficient of a specific polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Let 
$$
\begin{aligned}
f &= f(x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3,z_1,z_2,z_3)\\
&=(x_2+x_3-y_1-z_1)(x_1+x_3-y_2-z_2)(x_1+x_2-y_3-z_3)\\
&\times(y_2+y_3-x_1-z_1)(y_1+y_3-x_2-z_2)(y_1+y_2-x_3-z_3)\\
&\times(z_2+z_3-x_1-y_1)(z_1+z_3-x_2-y_2)(z_1+z_2-x_3-y_3)
\end{aligned}
$$

be a real multivariate polynomial.

I want to ask whether the coefficient of $x_1x_2x_3y_1y_2y_3z_1z_2z_3$ in $f$ is nonzero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is zero.

Define 6 variables
$$\begin{cases}
A_1 &= x_1 + x_2 + x_3\\
A_2 &= y_1 + y_2 + y_3\\
A_3 &= z_1 + z_2 + z_3
\end{cases}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\begin{cases}
B_1 &= x_1 + y_1 + z_1\\
B_2 &= x_2 + y_2 + z_2\\
B_3 &= x_3 + y_3 + z_3
\end{cases}
$$
The product at hand can be rewritten as

$$f = \prod_{i=1}^3\prod_{j=1}^3 (A_i - B_j) =
\begin{align}
\phantom{ \times } & (A_1 - B_1)(A_1 - B_2)(A_1-B_3)\\
    \times & (A_2-B_1)(A_2-B_2)(A_2-B_3)\\
    \times & (A_3-B_1)(A_3-B_2)(A_3-B_3)
\end{align}$$

Consider following bijection $\varphi$ on the 9 variables
$$(x_1, x_2, x_3, y_1, y_2, y_3, z_1, z_2, z_3)
\quad\mapsto\quad
  (x_1, y_1, z_1, x_2, y_2, z_2, x_3, y_3, z_3)$$
It can be extended to an involution of the polynomial ring formed from these 9 variables.
Under this involution, we have

$$\varphi(A_i) = B_i \quad\text{ and }\quad \varphi(B_i) = A_i\quad\text{ for } i = 1,2,3$$
This leads to

$$\varphi(f) = \prod_{i=1}^3 \prod_{j=1}^3 \varphi(A_i - B_j)
= (-1)^9 \prod_{i=1}^3 \prod_{j=1}^3 (A_j - B_i) = - f$$

Since the term we want to extract the coefficient: $x_1 y_1 z_1 x_2 y_2 z_2 x_3 y_3 z_3$ is invariant under $\varphi$. The corresponding coefficient will be equal to negative of itself. This forces that coefficient to be $0$.

Comment: I guess it's easier to see if we re-write the factors using 
$$
x_2 + x_3 - y_1 - z_1 = ( (x_1 + x_2 + x_3) - (x_1+ y_1 + z_1)) 
$$
I saw this too but I thought of using this to expand all the terms and didn't try thinking about a proof. Your convolution has the effect of transposing the $9$ factors displayed above in a $3 \times 3$-matrix fashion, giving a minus sign to each factor. Apparently it works! +1

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva this is actually how I get the answer...

Comment: I know, but you didn't write the re-writing explicitly so I wrote it down for the others. I'm aware that you knew!

Comment: Thank you very much! Your method also solve the case when $n$ is odd(my problem above is the case when $n=3$.But when $n$ is even, I think the coefficient is nonzero. But I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: @user173856, at least when $n = 2$, it is non-zero (equal to $4$).

Comment: By brute force, the coefficient for $n = 4$ seems to be $331776 = (4!)^4$.

Answer (score 0):

If my computations are correct, the coefficient is $0$.

Comment: You mean you threw this in some software?

Comment: That's certainly the easiest thing to do.

Comment: Isreal : I agree, a lot of terms seems to actually contribute to evaluating this coefficient. (I found more than three patterns which generate a bunch of non-zero terms if you expand...)

Comment: If you expand it out, there are some $13410$ terms.  Not too bad for a CAS.

Comment: Can you proof it?

Comment: You want me to prove that Maple has no bugs?

Comment: @RobertIsrael : There is a proof!